# A classloader problem related to spring-boot-devtools

Tags: spring-boot, classloader, dozer

Background:
Spring boot project, add goods and goods price list

```
Goods:
List<GoodsPrice> pricelist;
```

in controller first convert goodsForm to goods(by dozer), then save goods,after saving goods iterate goods price list to populate goodsId.

```
goods.getPriceList().forEach(p -> p.setGoodsId(goods.getId()));
```

When iterate goods price list, throw exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.foo.goods.model.GoodsPrice cannot be cast to com.foo.goods.model.GoodsPrice
at com.foo.goods.service.GoodsService$$Lambda$11/310447431.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
at com.foo.goods.service.GoodsService.saveGoods(GoodsService.java:34) ~[classes/:na]
```

Somebody remind me this exception related to classloader, and in eclipse debug mode, I outputed the GoodsPrice's ClassLoader:

```
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@14dad5dc
```

and goods:
    `org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@591c6338`

Indeed exist diff classloader. 
Then I commented `spring-boot-devtools` then tried again this time it's ok.
So if still retain `spring-boot-devtools`, how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 7):

Dozer is using the wrong classloader.
You can solve it adding this file in your resource folder :
META-INF/spring-devtools.properties
with inside :

restart.include.dozer=/dozer-5.5.1.jar

restart.include.dozer-spring=/dozer-spring-5.5.1.jar  (only if you use this jar!)

sources : http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-devtools-customizing-classload

Comment: I have the same issue, but not in a Spring context. I am using Liferay Developer Studio (which is basically an enhanced Eclipse) and using Orika instead of Dozer. Do you know how should I go in order to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

The same has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54397850/spring-devtools-not-included-in-the-fat-jar-packaged-with-spring-boot-maven-plug).

You need to set the excludeDevTools to false

Comment: If the linked answer also answers this queastion you should vote to close this question as a duplicate.