# Hibernate custom class mapping

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

When I fech users using this code, it works as desired.

```
 public List<Users> getActiveUsers(User user) {
    EntityManager entityManager = getEntityManager();
   List<User> Users = new ArrayList();
    try {
        users = entityManager.createQuery("select e from User e where  e.deleted = :deleted", User.class)
                .setParameter("deleted", false)                 
                .getResultList();
    } finally {
        entityManager.close();
    }
    return users;
}
```

But if I try to get only one user using th following code, it fails.

```
User user = (User) entityManager.createQuery("select e from User e where  e.deleted = :deleted")
                .setParameter("deleted", false)+                 
                .getSingleResult();
```

I can't get a mapped user, the excepction is: "can't convert com.project.model.User to com.project.model.User"

Comment: Can you try using  `entityManager.createQuery(query, User.class)`? Where do you deploy this?

Comment: I have tried it, same result. Where I deploy? Not sure if I understand, it is in localhost and the method is being called in a userRepositoryCustom class

Comment: What application server are you using, this seems a problem related to a classloader. Also try adding to your query "setMaxResults(1)".

Comment: I am using Glassfish

Comment: Can you add the log?

Comment: This is the error I get: `Can not pass an instance of "class com.project.model.User (loaded by instance of sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader(id=8597))" to an instance of "class com.project.model.User (loaded by instance of org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.Restar‌​tClassLoader(id=1241‌​4))"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there was nothing wrong with the code. What I found out to be the problem was the same as this guy:

[A classloader proplem related to spring-boot-devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33957612/a-classloader-proplem-related-to-spring-boot-devtools)

however, the .properties file with the dozer reference did not work for me. I managed to get my code up and running by removing spring-devtools from the project. Guess I can live without live reload!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put the class type **`User.class`**:

```
entityManager.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u where  u.deleted = :deleted", User.class)
             .setParameter("deleted", false).getSingleResult();
```

Your method:

```
 public User getActiveUser(User user) {
    EntityManager entityManager = getEntityManager();      
    try {
        User user = (User) = entityManager.createQuery
                           ("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.deleted = :deleted", User.class)
                           .setParameter("deleted", false).getSingleResult();
    } finally {
        entityManager.close();
    }
    return user;
}
```

- Look on first example, you use Users class and on second User (without S in the end)
- You need to be care with this query, because they may be returned more than one record

Comment: I have tried with both, casting (User) and adding User.class

Comment: I have tried that, and this is the error I get `Can not pass an instance of  "class com.project.model.User (loaded by instance of sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader(id=8597))" to an instance of "class com.project.model.User (loaded by instance of org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader(id=12414))"`