# FileNotFoundException: class path resource [FileChangeListener.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: spring, spring-boot

spring devtools are not included in the fat executable jar which gives this error if we try to run the spring boot jar using "java -jar " command.

Answer (score 0):

Devtools are excluded by default in spring boot project. So we need to prevent that.
The following page contains the detailed answer: [Spring DevTools not included in the fat jar packaged with spring-boot-maven-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54397850/spring-devtools-not-included-in-the-fat-jar-packaged-with-spring-boot-maven-plug)